# Datalogger with PI

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, raspberry-pi

I am building a datalogger with raspberry pi. I have used a Shell script in `rc.local`, I am capturing the Bytes using `tcpdump`. The Problem am facing is that the log file is getting replaced each and every time the pi boots on. Is there a way possible to save the log files with different names every time the pi starts.

my intial code in `rc.local`

```
tcpdump -w new.pcap //this writes all the Frames of Ethernet to the file new.pcap
```

I have tried appending the data but I want to save the log file each and every time the pi boots.

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks for the edit. Now it's more professional. How do I write like that. Could you pls shed some light on how to highlight the linux codes!! Thanks!!

Comment: [Start here.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and read [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) too (though you don't have enough rep to upvote yet).

Answer (score 3):

How about setting the log file name to a timestamp:

```
 tcpdump -w new.`date +%s`.pcap
```

Which will stick a number in there that represents the current time (in seconds since 1970, which is how Unix stores it).

Or alternatively:

```
tcpdump -w new.`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.pcap
```

(Date formatted for easier sorting)

Comment: Thank you!!

tcpdump -w new.`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.pcap // will this store the date, Name, min, sec to the name of the file or time at which each Frame is captured by tcpdump.'

Comment: I tried with both the commands. The string characters are displayed as such and not with the corresponding date and time. Could you tell me what was the problme with that!!

Comment: Make sure you don't miss out the backticks.  Or use `$(date ...)`.

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for the tip. The Problem with using the date and time is that, there's no RTC in raspberry and so the files take the Name of the last active time and so the file keeps on overwring at the same time. Is there anyother way possible to store the file in different Names each time the pi boots up.

Comment: Have a look at `logrotate`; I am sure you could set that up with a simple config file to rotate the old dump before you start `tcpdump` again. E.g., so you end up with `whatever.pcap.1`, `whatever.pcap.2`, etc.  It will also optionally compress them for you.